# Stripe API request working with Postman but failing with Apex Rest Callout

Tags: apex, rest, http, stripe

I'm trying to make a callout to a Stripe Api with Apex. I made the exactly same request in Postman with the same Http configuration and have this working well. But when running it with Apex i get a Http 400 (Bad Request) with this error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This property cannot be expanded (data).",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to query a list of Payment Intents from stripe and expand the balance transaction stored in the payment charge data. And here is how I do it

```
Http http = new Http();

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(); 
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer Token');  
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

String payload = 'expand[]=data.charges.data.balance_transaction';

request.setMethod('GET');

request.setEndpoint(API_ENDPOINT + '/v1/payment_intents');

request.setBody(payload);

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

System.debug(response.getBody());
```

Can anyone help me please to understand what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you actually appending the token string to the Authorization header, `request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+TokenVARIABLE);`?

Comment: @gale-force-wizard This is not how i did it in my code. I wrote the authorization like that just for readers to have the different steps of my approach. I have no authorization problem and all requests without requestBody works. After testing a lot of time i think the problem is in my way of defining body for my stripe requests. But i still do not have find a way to do that well and make it work.

Comment: Salesforce doesn't support `GET` with body. That's why they're failing, those requests are actually sent as `POST` which the external system doesn't recognise.

Comment: @SachinHooda when I make a `GET` on a single payment_intent with `expand[]=charges.data.balance_transaction` as body I have the result and my balance_transaction is expanded as wished. And my logs also tell me that the callout made is a `GET`. But if Salesforce really change my request Method do you know a way to make a `GET` to an API wanted us to give a body to the request? Thanks

Comment: @SachinHooda I think you were right. Make the same request on postman with `POST` method give me the same errors. So is there any way to byparse that or that is just impossible with saleforces?

Comment: Not sure if there is any way possible. Had this issue twice hopefully the external system also had `SOAP`. Maybe you can try calling `Stripe support` they could have any other way possible.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the Authorization token correctly. sToken (SessionID)

```
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sToken);
```

Also could you check your payload ? I believe you are able to make the call but the payload is incorrect.

Comment: Yes I have authorization and my callouts are working since the error message I get come from stripe and is not a 401(Unauthorized) meaning that I correctly reached my stripe data source. I think you are right about the payload but I still do not have find a way to make it work with Apex. When I make a query on a single payment_intent with `expand[]=charges.data.balance_transaction` as payload I have the result and my balance_transaction is expanded as wished. So I don't understand why the same logic for the payload with a list of payment_intent is not working but work when testing with postman